# VHDL code to convert 5 bit vector to integer

Tags: vhdl

I am stuck in the following problem-

I need to write a VHDL function that converts 5 bit vector to integer where integer value of binary number a4a3a2a1a0 can be computed as (((0 + a4)* + a3)* + a2 )* +a1)* +a0. 
This is not any homework. But I am preparing for my exams.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `(0 + a4)*` signify? It is not familiar syntax to me, at least not in VHDL.

Comment: Initialize your result variable to 0. Loop through each bit of the vector from MSB to LSB, multiply by 2 and then add 1 if the current bit is set.

Answer (score 2):

If your binary number a4a3a2a1a0 is an std_logic_vector, you can use standard conversion functions:

```
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
```

.

```
integer_result <= to_integer(unsigned(input_vector));
```

The NUMERIC_STD library must have been used for this to work.

In many cases it may be possible to use 'unsigned' as the type of the input vector, removing one conversion stage.